# React: Conditional Rendering Of Components And Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, jsx

Here I'm trying to return each item in the array as an h1 so the print to screen should look like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

However I get this error:

Warning: Charts(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

How can I achieve this?

```
import React from 'react';

function NoCharts(props) {
  return <h1>No charts</h1>;
}

function Charts(props) {
  const myCharts = props.myCharts;
  if (myCharts.length > 0) {

    myCharts.forEach(function(chart) {
        return <h1>{chart}</h1>;
    });

  }
  return <NoCharts />;
}


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

      let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

    return (
      <div>

        <Charts myCharts={arr} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must "return" a valid React element, as the error says -

> Charts(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

```
if (myCharts.length > 0) {

    const charts = myCharts.map(function(chart) {
        return <h1>{chart}</h1>;
    });
    return <div>{charts}</div>

  }
  else {
     return <NoCharts />;
  }
}
```

Here's the working app on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nyxx/full/OgrbEr/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return myCharts. Currently you're only returning something when the array is empty.

```
    return myCharts.forEach(function(chart) {
      return <h1>{chart}</h1>;
    });
```